# How can I restore ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

At some point the SSIS cleanup job login (##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##) got deleted from my sql server (2012). I'm trying to upgrade to SP2 and I'm getting an error message I believe is related to this user being missing from the server.

I still have the appropriate User in the SSIS database, but I need to re-create the login. However, I can't find what settings (passwords etc) to use.

The only thing I could find about restoring this user was [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS), but it doesn't give enough detail.

> 6.1. Create login [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##] using CREATE LOGIN TSQL statement. This login is for internal use in SSISDB maintenance.

> 6.2. Map SSISDB user ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser## to server login ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##

```
 USE SSISDB
 ALTER USER [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] with LOGIN = [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##]
```

How can I recreate this login properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to experiment with creating the user with a random password, and everything worked.

```
CREATE LOGIN [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##] WITH PASSWORD=N'blahblahblah', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

USE SSISDB
GO
ALTER USER [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] with LOGIN = [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##]
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to server migration also, job failing, executed

```
USE SSISDB
GO
ALTER USER [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser##] with LOGIN = [##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin##]
```

And fixed the job